# How to customize the behaviour of SecurityContextPersistenceFilter?

Tags: multithreading, spring-security, spring-boot, servlet-filters, security-context

I developing a stateless REST API that makes use of token based authentication, where I'm manually adding an Authentication object to the security context by calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)` from within a custom security filter. I've been experiencing problems with the context not being set correctly which I believe is due to this :

[Storing the SecurityContext between requests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-intro-sec-context-persistence)

> In an application which receives concurrent requests in a single session, the same SecurityContext instance will be shared between threads. Even though a ThreadLocal is being used, it is the same instance that is retrieved from the HttpSession for each thread. This has implications if you wish to temporarily change the context under which a thread is running. If you just use SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), and call setAuthentication(anAuthentication) on the returned context object, then the Authentication object will change in all concurrent threads which share the same SecurityContext instance. ...
>
> You can customize the behaviour of SecurityContextPersistenceFilter to create a completely new SecurityContext for each request, preventing changes in one thread from affecting another.

So the question is - how do you change the behaviour of the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter?

I'd like the security context to not be associated with the http session, but don't want to set the session creation policy to stateless, because I still want to implement CSRF protection etc.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact question this afternoon, and this open question matched my search exactly, so I thought I would add the little I learned.

We had threads that were accessing the same SecurityContext. I was unable to figure out how to customize the behavior of the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter directly (and in the pattern of the framework), however there were two ways that I could get it to be thread safe.

The first solution was to ensure that an empty context was created in our main authentication filter. This covered all of our authenticated requests, so it would work for our solution.

```
SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
```

The second thing that worked for me was to change our WebSecurityConfig to be stateless, which I know doesn't work for the OP, but added here for completeness.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
  .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  ...
```

Both these solutions work independently for our particular configuration. I'm certain there is a 3rd solution that would read better, but I don't know what it is but would like to.

This is my first time posting. I welcome any feedback.